# What steps are required to allow custom workflows in my SharePoint list?

Tags: designer-workflow, administration, business

I am not an administrator for SharePoint just a user. I have in times past used custom workflows and custom ASPX pages for my sharepoint sites.

I am in anew organization and they do not allow custom workflows, SharePoint designer access or other thing that are not OOTB (out of the box).

I have been asked to tell them what needs to be done to 'turn on' custom workflows and SharePoint designer access. Where would I look for this information and good rational why it should be on?

Also, my understanding is that I can turn these things on for individual site access. Is this correct or do I have to turn it on across the whole environment?

Answer (score 0):

under site settigns - > site administration. you can enable the designer access for each site collection.

for workflows, you should check it under web application management - workflow settings - > user defined workflows (yes or no)

Answer (score 0):

For Sharepoint Designer Access. It is two step process.

1. Enable it from `central admin, central Admin > Application Management > Manage web Applications >` then select the Web application where you want enable the designer access.

   a. From the Ribbon click on the General settings

   b. On this dropdown, select SharePoint designer

   c. Now on this page check the boxes.[image]
2. enable at site collections level.

https://redmondmag.com/articles/2015/03/19/sharepoint-designer-tool.aspx